# Как комсомолец — коммунисту

Tags: тире

Как следует ставить знаки в предложениях подобного рода? Допустим: я тебе говорю (,) как брат (—) брату. Предложение в заголовке взято из книги "Generation П" В.О. Пелевина.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Я тебе говорю как брат — брату.**

Запятая не нужна, здесь значение "в качестве".
А тире - интонационное: необязательное, но логичное

Answer (score 1):

Устойчивое сочетание *как брат брату* = по-братски (нареч.), как и пословица: *брат брату рад*, в тире не нуждается. Фразе в теме вопроса «как комсомолец — коммунисту» тире необходимо, оно замещает контекстом обусловленный глагол.

Answer (score 1):

Если два человека действительно являются братьями — то это отождествление (можно по смыслу подставить "являясь братом") и запятая не нужна.

А если это просто друзья или знакомые — то это сравнение и нужна запятая:
*Я тебе говорю так, как брат говорит брату.

Я тебе говорю, как брат брату.*

Если делать **интонационную паузу**, то можно поставить интонационное тире. Хотя мне кажется, что пауза там не делается. Но это больше на усмотрение автора.

Если существительные разные (комсомолец и коммунист), то интонационное тире гораздо больше подходит, чтобы подчеркнуть разницу между словами. И пауза там довольно логична.
*Как комсомолец — коммунисту.*